# Print nth column from a CSV file, where myScript.sh reads the table and the column argument is combined like: "col1,col2,col3" in one argument

Tags: bash, csv, printing, arguments

If I have a script which takes three arguments like so:

```
./myScript.sh path file col1,col3
```

and if file is like:

```
id,role,salary
05,engineer,45000
```

How would I split $3 into separate variables (note that this could be any number of variables, if I had a larger CSV file) in order to only print the corresponding columns to $3.

I've tried saving $3 to a variable, using Tr and array to possible equate the index of the array to the column header number. I failed to do this. What is the most simplistic amateurish approach to resolving this? It would be straight forward if the script took the columns as separate arguments, but when combined in one argument, it's complicating this quite a bit for me.

Expected output:

```
id,salary
05,45000
```

Comment: Note: Splitting $3 is not necessary if there is a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of the columns must stay the same:

```
#!/bin/bash

path="$1"
fname="$2"
cols="$3"

header=($(head -1 "$fname" | sed 's/,/ /g'))

for i in "${!header[@]}"; do
    cols=$(echo "$cols" | sed "s/${header[$i]}/$((i+1))/g")
done

cut -d',' -f$cols $fname
```

If you need more flexibility e.g. define the order of columns, just change the last part  of the script with this:

```
for i in "${!header[@]}"; do
    cols=$(echo "$cols" | sed -e "s/${header[$i]}/\$$((i+1))/g")
done

awk -F, "{print(${cols//,/\",\"})}" $fname
```

Output:

```
$ ./so.sh <path> input.txt id,salary
id,salary
05,45000
```

With the `awk` method, you can do stuff like

```
$ ./so.sh <path> input.txt id,salary,id,salary
id,salary,id,salary
05,45000,05,45000
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Really appreciate it. Would you mind explaining how it works?

Specifically:
- declare -A rheader
- "${!header[@]}"
- --output-delimiter=','

Comment: I removed the `declare -A rheader` and the `--output-delimiter`, they're not needed anymore. To get the keys of an array, you would use the syntax `${!<array_name>[@]}`.

Comment: Understood! Last question. Could you explain what's happening in this line?

cols=$(echo "$cols" | sed -e "s/${header[$i]}/\$$((i+1))/g")

Sorry, I'm a real amateur. I understand we are using sed to substitute values, but I'm not quite sure how it's working progression wise.

Comment: Remember that `cols` contain the comma separated list of the columns that you want to print, `sed` will replace each column name `${header[$i}` with the column index `\$$((i+1))`. The extra `$` at the beginning of `$((i+1))` is needed for `awk`.